# Недоступность кода после return

Tags: java

Имеется такой вот метод:

```
public static void asd(){
  return;
  int x = 20;
  System.out.println(x);
}
```

IDE (смотрел в нетбинсе и эклипсе) ругается на недоступность кода после return;

[image: Imgur]

но если поменять return; на if(true) return;

```
public static void asd(){
  if(true) return;
  int x = 20;
  System.out.println(x);
}
```

IDE NetBeans перестает ругаться, а Eclipse просто выводит варнинг, и компилятор все это дело проглатывает.

[image: Imgur]

Вопрос: почему же так? )) Спасибо

Comment: просто проверки IDE unreachable statement

Comment: В народе второй вариант получил название "Индусский код" :)

Comment: @impe, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В данном случае вы рассуждаете как человек. Человеку очевидно, что в обоих ситуациях выполнится только return.

Однако с точки зрения компилятора не все так однозначно. Дело в том, что компилятор не имеет права принимать решения за пользователя, он имеет право лишь ему подсказывать. 
В первом случае код является заведомо ошибочным - код после return не вполнится никогда. Поэтому здесь компилятор может сигнализировать об ошибке.

Однако во втором случае не все так однозначно - хоть условие и является всегда истинным, компилятор не может знать, написано ли это по ошибке, или пользователь действительно этого хочет (например, такое условие может быть заглушкой для какого-то if, который будет реализован впоследствии). Учитывая, что компилятор не может знать, что именно хочет пользователь и не вправе принимать за него решения, то в данной ситуации он может лишь предупредить о возможной ошибке.

Comment: да, все логично и верно сказано ) спс

Comment: Еще можно через рефлекшн заменить значение true на false и код после условия сработает.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, зачем так все усложнять. Методы void не возвращают значения. return прекращает работу void метода в момент появления, в вашем случае - в самом начале. "if (true) return" будет всегда приводить к выполнению return и прекращению выполнения метода, т.е. остальное тело метода все равно будет являться dead code.
Если нужно было вернуть значение переменной для дальнейшего использования и при этом вывести в консоль её значение, то решение будет следующим:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = asd();
    System.out.println(a);
        }

public static int asd() {
    int x = 20;
    return x;
}
```

Если же просто вывести в консоль, то следующее:

```
 public static void asd(){
 int x = 20;
 System.out.println(x);
 }
```

Comment: Речь совершенно не о том, чего ТС хочет добиться в коде. А о том, почему IDE и компилятор способны ругаться только на простейшие случаи unreachable code, храня тишину при малейших усложнениях.